# SQL doesn't join necessary tables in HotChocolate pagination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql, hotchocolate

I have the following entity `Space` that has a collection of `SpaceMessage`

```cs
public class Space
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true, MaxPageSize = 50)]
    public ICollection<SpaceMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new HashSet<SpaceMessage>();
}
```

The query is defined as

```cs
    [UseFirstOrDefault]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    public IQueryable<Space> GetSpace(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, int id)
    {
        return dbContext.Spaces.Where(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

Now I want to query messages of space 1 with pagination.

```
query {
    space(id: 1) {
        messages(first: 1) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But returns an empty collection

```
{
  "data": {
    "space": {
      "messages": {
        "edges": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's because the SQL doesn't join the massage table

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[@__id_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
      FROM [Spaces] AS [s]
      WHERE [s].[Id] = @__id_0
```

If there is any workaround of this it is highly appreciated.

Comment: HotChocolate 13.3.1, .NET 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now paging is not supported for the navigation properties, and HotChocolate has [the bug](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/4841) about it

[The only workaround](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/4214#issuecomment-916724556) is to define a resolver instead of navigation property:

```cs
public class Space
{
    [IsProjected]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true, MaxPageSize = 50)]
    public IQueryable<SpaceMessage> GetSpaceMessages(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.SpaceMessages.Where(e => e.SpaceId == Id);
    }

}
```